# Why is ComputeHash() still blocking UI thread in an async task?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, md5

So let me explain : I'm making a file signature scanner in C# using MD5 to compute the hashes. A problem I encountered is that `ComputeHash()` would block the UI thread. So then I thought of `Task.Run()`, which would solve my problems, at least *I hoped so*.

Even when putting the hash computing (and the whole) in an async task, it would still block, or at least, *slow down the UI thread*. And if I remove that hash computing, the UI thread isn't blocked anymore.

Here is my little snippet of code :

```
Task.Run(() =>
        {
            if (int.Parse(label5.Text) != int.Parse(label7.Text))
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex++;
                label11.Text = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

                /*progressBar1.Increment(1);
                label5.Text = progressBar1.Value.ToString();
                int percentage = Convert.ToInt32(progressBar1.Value / (double)progressBar1.Maximum * 100);
                label2.Text = "Scanning files (" + percentage + "%)";*/
                label2.Text = "Scanning";

                label9.Text = currentThreats.ToString();
                try
                {
                    StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
                    using (MD5 md5 = MD5.Create())
                    {
                        using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(label11.Text))
                        {
                            byte[] hash = md5.ComputeHash(stream);
                            buff.Append(BitConverter.ToString(hash).Replace("-", string.Empty));
                        }
                    }

                    if (Reference.VirusList.Contains(buff.ToString())) currentThreats++;
                }
                catch { }

                scanned++;
                label5.Text = scanned.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                StopCurrentScan(false);
            }
        });
```

**NOTE** : This is being run in a Timer with an interval of *1 millisecond*. Just precising it in case it might help solve the problem.

Comment: The UI thread is special - it's meant to be the only one that accesses UI objects. So you need to *stop* manipulating listboxes, labels, etc when you're not on the UI thread. That's your first problem.

Comment: As an aside, generating deliberate MD5 collisions has become [very simple](https://www.mscs.dal.ca/~selinger/md5collision/), and cryptographically MD5 is considered completely broken. If `VirusList` is an indication of your use case and the files can't necessarily be trusted, relying on a simple MD5 hash to verify the presence or absence of changes is not a good idea.

Comment: 1) You need `await Task.Run()`. 2) Only put the `md5.ComputeHash()` call inside Task.Run() (or the whole `using` statement). 3) Do **NOT** access the UI controls inside Task.Run() because it runs on a worker thread.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Okay, but this doesn't really answer my question, because UI thread isn't blocked if I update anything UI-related. My problem is related in a built-in .NET function (or at least that's what I think).

Comment: @41686d6564 if I use await Task.Run() (and I put my functions async) then my code seems to be broken, and I don't see why the keyword await is needed since Task.Run will run async anyways.

If I try to only put the whole using statement in an async task then the UI thread will still block, no matter what. Also, as I mentionned on my above comment, the problem is not by accessing UI elements from a seperate thread.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that the UI thread isn't blocked at all but simply slowed down by the I/O generated in the other thread(s)? If the file is large and your drive isn't fast the impact on the system can be considerable. Doubly so if you allow multiple of these scans to occur in parallel (starting one before another has finished).

Comment: SInce you run the code in a timer with only 1ms interval, I guess all the CPU time is spent, so there is not much more resource for the UI thread. Check the resource monitor.

Comment: You could consider adding the following line at the start of your application. It will protect you from shooting yourself in the foot. `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = true;`

Comment: @Theodor Zoulias Isn't it already on by default?

Comment: I think not. If it was, your program would crash. Which is a good thing, because you are doing things that you are not supposed to do.

Comment: Well after adding this, my program doesn't crash but the timer doesn't execute anymore.

Comment: Indeed, the task created by `Task.Run` is not awaited, so any exception that may occur inside the task will remain unobserved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, now my UI thread isn't lagging out as hell anymore since I followed the steps below that people suggested me to do :

1. I used `await Task.Run()` instead of `Task.Run()` to log exceptions, and I added `Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreads = true;` just after `InitializeComponent` so I could better understand my mistakes.
2. I removed **ALL** UI thread calls (like updating UI elements) from the async task, I instead (in my case) use a timer that updates the UI elements I need from local variables.
3. Similar to **2.** but reversed, that means only "resource-intensive" tasks (like `ComputeHash()`) are in my async task.